# What good reference books for aviation (ATC & AOC) systems are there?

Tags: radio-communications, books

I am looking for a good reference book or research paper that describes the services and applications offered by [air traffic control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_traffic_control) and [Aeronautical Operational Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeronautical_Operational_Control) *in detail*.

Everything I have read so far just outlines briefly what these services are intended for. I need something very thorough with all the standardizations and details that are being used in current aviation systems, particularly from a communications point of view. Any suggestions?

What are the best textbooks or reference books that aviation researchers or experts use?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're asking for (it seems like a very broad question) but you could start with the [FAA's ATC orders](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf). Reading through that will give you a good picture of what ATC actually does. If you're specifically interested in standard radio phraseology, Appendix A of the orders gives the standard US phrasing for most things, with a lot of ICAO phrasing too. If that doesn't help, please try to make your question more specific.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you. Is there an FAA AOP order or a similar document on AOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with the [Global Operational Data Link Document](https://www.icao.int/APAC/Documents/edocs/GOLD_2Edition.pdf) published by ICAO.

It covers pretty much everything data link.  What it doesn't cover, you'll find in the referenced documents.